# How to change the width of one column in a table

Tags: tables, column-width

This is my table:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   %Presets from my institute
\newcolumntype{M}{X<{\vspace{4pt}}} %Presets from my institute

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| M | M | M |}
\hline
& \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{some text that is too long for this column}\\[-3ex]
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With this output:

[image: My table]

I want to decrease the width of the first column (and consequently increase the width of the second and third column) so that the text of the third column fits in one line.

I searched a lot but could not find a solution that I understood and that worked for me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already try with "l"  instead of the first "M"?

Comment: I would guess columns 1 and 2 should both be `l` not `M` (also why the `[-3ex]` making the rule over-print the text?

Comment: Thanks guys, that actually was the solution. I was so caught up in the issue that I tried a lot of complicated approaches but not the simple one.
[-3ex] was there because without it the row was too high. Now with the "l" instead of the "M" in the first column, it works without the [-3ex].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   %Presets from my institute
\newcolumntype{M}{X<{\vspace{4pt}}} %Presets from my institute

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{\dimexpr.10\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.65\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% column 3
  }
\hline
& \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{some text that is too long for this column}\\
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\textbf{text} & a number & a number\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can change the `dimexp` values to match 1 according to your data

[image: This is the end result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This also solves my problem. I tried that approach before but forgot to change "tabularx" to "tabular" and remove the "{\textwidth}". Therefore it didn't work back then.